# How can I provide the right parameter to this React Native Typescript navigation problem

Tags: react-native, navigation, components, react-navigation

I’m following a video tutorial, but I got stuck, the facilitator doesn’t specify a parameter type, and my application doesn’t work accordingly due to this issue

I guess it’s a simple solution
The app implements a simple navigation:

```
export const Routes: React.FC<RoutesProps> = ({}) => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

And the components used to navigate to

```
function Login({navigation}) {
    return (
        <Center>
            <Text style={styles.text}>I'm a Login Screen</Text>
            <Button
                title="go to register"
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate("Register")
                }} 
            />
        </Center>
    );
}

function Register({navigation}) {
    return (
        <Center>
            <Text style={styles.text}>I'm a Register Screen</Text>
            <Button
                title="go to Login"
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate("Login")
                }} 
            />
        </Center>
    );
}
```

The buttons “go to Register” and “go to Login” are displayed correctly, but they don’t do anything, I guess it’s due to the fact that the parameter navigation type is not specified, and I don´t know how it is provided either

I even changed the compiler settings to "noImplicitAny": false, but it didn´t solve the problem, as I expected, it doesn't show an error, but it doesn't work

Could anybody help me with this issue

Rafael

Comment: Check the documentation it might help https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by executing npm install expo-cli --global